# How to refer to field name dynamically using a variable in MS Access VB

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, field

I'm making a search form for keyword searches. I have comboboxes with values ["And","Or","Not"], comboboxes with a list of field names, e.g. ["Title","Description",...] and textboxes associated with each combobox. I'm trying to create the sql query based on the values of the comboboxes and text box. To do that, I need to refer to the field name based on the value of the combobox. I'm trying solutions I've found searching, but I'm still getting the error: "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined". The debugger highlights "VHS_Metadata_Aug52014(field)" in yellow.

.....

```
bool_type = Me!Controls!dropBoolType2.value

field = Me!Controls!dropSearch2.value

value = Me!Controls!txtKeywords2.value

If (value) > 0 Then

    SQL_query_string = SQL_query_string & " " & bool_type & " " & VHS_Metadata_Aug52014(field) = " & value"

End If
```

.....

Comment: And what is `VHS_Metadata_Aug52014`? The syntax: `VHS_Metadata_Aug52014()` is that of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use dot notation instead. Using bangs like that doesn't let you use variables very easily. Try something like

```
Forms("formname").controls(foo).value
```

Where foo is the value from the combobox.

I'm not sure what VHS_Metadata_Aug52014 is though, if it's the name of the form you were trying to reference, you were partly there.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm in the habit of using the ! because in the code editor in Access, when I type a "!", intellisense helps me find the control name, but not with ".". Makes no sense to me.